# css bootstrap full screen issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been able to set a full screen background in my website. It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is when I make the window smaller. It looks like this:

[image]

And if i scroll down the site, the result is this ugly thing:

[image]

Do you know how could I solve this? I have the same issue when I try to see the site from a mobile:

[image]

Once the problem has been statedm let's see the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slides fullscreen-bg fullscreen-bg__img text-center">
        <p id="slide1" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%;  opacity:1;  ">
            <img  class="img-responsive" alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="~/Content/Images/Portada2.jpg" height: "auto">
        </p>
        <p id="slide2" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; opacity:0; ">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="~/Content/Images/Portada.JPG">
        </p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;

}

.fullscreen-bg__img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:#000; 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.img-responsive {

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {

    position: relative;
    margin-top: -15%;
}
```

I leave a link to the site in case you want to reproduce the errors yourselves:

http://ulrickpsp-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.slides p {
    width: auto !important;
}
.slides p img {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This isn't perfect. You get image distortion at very tall portrait aspect ratios. It would be better if your images were backgrounds on div elements.

Comment: I added something that seems to be necessary for mobile (portrait) aspect ratios.

Comment: Oh! I've noticed one more bug. Now in the main screen everything is fine, but when the background changes, if I make the window small, there's another issue. Only for that image :S

Comment: Please open a new question for new issues.

Answer (score -2):

please if you use as background. we have css3 property `background-size: cover`
or if you as html need to make from javascript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: The images aren't backgrounds.

Answer (score -3):

Edit the pictures in a photoprogram (f.exam PhotoFiltre) And make the the two pictures into one.